# How to block directory by htaccess but allow for my site over GET

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

I've got 2 servers - web server and data server, where are all my uploaded files. Is there any option in htaccess to block all access in data server, but allow for requests from that web server?

Example: web server: portal with videos, audio,... and data server, where are        all files uploaded. I need to block download (access) all these files direct from "dataserver/file" (and all subfolders), but I need to access these files for example via `<video src="dataserver/file"></video>`, which is called from webserver (man comes to my site and want to see the movie/audio/...)

Comment: When you link using the `<video>` tag, the browser still has to directly request the video from your dataserver, just like if someone typed it into the URL location bar. Your webserver isn't downloading anything, it's just providing a link to where a browser can find the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A visitor's browser on parsing the `<video>` tag will make the request to your data server directly. Your web server isn't involved there. But, what you want to prevent, which in web terminology is called *hot-linking*, is possible.

Basically, every browser request has a *referer* field attached to it (whenever available), which lets the server know the website a user is coming from. For e.g., say, you open your browser and go to `google.com`, Google will receive your request with no *referer* because that's the first site you opened in that browser tab.

But, when you search and click on a link to go to a website, that server will receive the complete URL of the Google page that you clicked the link on to reach that website passed to it as the HTTP *referer* request header.

So, on your data server, you can have an .htaccess that makes sure that clients are making video requests from your website only by checking their *referer* headers. Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?webserver\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(swf|flv|mp4)$ - [F,L]
```

This would also prevent the users from just typing in the video URL in the browser in the hopes of downloading it directly. The hot-linkers would now receive a *403 Forbidden* error.

This however does have the potential to break your site for people browsing it with some sort of privacy software installed that strips every browser request of the *referer* field. So, that's your trade-off here.

Comment: Thank you, http_referer should be the right way... just, what about that break, what do you mean with that privacy software and strips every browser request? What kind of software is it? Basic antivirus or some "special browsers for hacker with anonymity"?

Comment: Security suite apps like McAfee and Symantec sometimes also provide software that can block ads, remove tracking cookies, remove referer from outgoing requests and other features that help the user remain relatively more anonymous while browsing the Internet. The videos would fail to load for such users who are withholding their referer information through such apps.